# How to use ng-cloak in Ionic 3/ Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a Ionic 3 app with a search function. When the search is applied and there is no result, the following card is shown well:

```
  <ion-card *ngIf="pages?.length == 0" ng-cloak>
    <ion-card-content>
      No pages found...
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

But when the pages loads, it flickers on the screen :(
So I used the ng-cloak to hide on load. I added this CSS:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

in the app.scss

But when the pages loads, the ion-card flickered on the screen...

Comment: use this style `[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}`

Comment: @sachilaranawaka, thanks. As I understand your answer, you suggest to remove [x-ng-cloak], .x-ng-cloak, is that right? To understand this. What are those doing?

Comment: add ts code as well.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa thank you for your answer. Whitch ts code do you mean? Angular use to handle ng-cloak, right?

Comment: Angular doesn't support ngCloak, Add ts i will show you other way to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular does not support `ngCloak`. You can use this approach in angular -

**HTML**

```
 <ion-card *ngIf="showNotFound">
    <ion-card-content>
      No pages found...
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

**TS**

```
showNotFound: boolean = false

    search() {
        this.showNotFound = false;
        this.api.search(queryText).subscribe(data => {
                this.results = data;
                try {
                    if (!this.results.length) {
                        this.showNotFound = true;
                    }
                } catch (exception) {
                    console.error(exception);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works good right now! I've made one addition after the if: else { this.showNotFound = false } because when the user can type a searchresult who gives result the card must disappear.